# TortoiseSVN error's when pushing to Codeplex

Tags: tortoisesvn, codeplex

I'm trying to submit a project to codeplex - and I can't push up my source code so I'm now 15 days away from having it deleted off their servers.

I'm using tortoisesvn and have never had this issue w/ my own svn server.

Here's the log from my commit:

```
D:\Development\ChildLinksUpgrade
D:\Development\ChildLinksUpgrade\ChildLinksUpgrade
D:\Development\ChildLinksUpgrade\ChildLinksUpgrade\ChildLinksUpgrade.csproj
D:\Development\ChildLinksUpgrade\ChildLinksUpgrade\ImportModule.cs
D:\Development\ChildLinksUpgrade\ChildLinksUpgrade\License.txt
D:\Development\ChildLinksUpgrade\ChildLinksUpgrade\Properties
D:\Development\ChildLinksUpgrade\ChildLinksUpgrade\Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs
D:\Development\ChildLinksUpgrade\ChildLinksUpgrade\ReleaseNotes.txt
D:\Development\ChildLinksUpgrade\ChildLinksUpgrade\ViewChildLinksUpgrade.ascx
D:\Development\ChildLinksUpgrade\ChildLinksUpgrade\ViewChildLinksUpgrade.ascx.cs
D:\Development\ChildLinksUpgrade\ChildLinksUpgrade\ViewChildLinksUpgrade.ascx.designer.cs
D:\Development\ChildLinksUpgrade\ChildLinksUpgrade\_readMe.txt
D:\Development\ChildLinksUpgrade\ChildLinksUpgrade\web.Debug.config
D:\Development\ChildLinksUpgrade\ChildLinksUpgrade\web.Release.config
D:\Development\ChildLinksUpgrade\ChildLinksUpgrade\web.config
Commit failed (details follow):
At least one property change failed; repository is unchanged
The PROPPATCH request returned invalid XML in the response: XML parse error at
 line 1: no element found (/svn/!svn/wrk/1c9ef6fb-1a14-9348-afe4-7a1d77a51333)
```

I'm using the most recent version of TortoiseSVN.

Comment: Is the error consistent? What version of TortoiseSVN? What steps did you followed?

Comment: I also get this when I try to commit changes to properties (e.g. svn::ignore).  If your only property changes are svn::ignores then it is probably safe to only commit your source files.

Comment: Yes - it's everytime I try to commit.  Using Tortoise SVN 1.7.3.22386.

I've since switched to using TFS - and at least got it pushed up.  Would like to fix for SVN though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hate to make this the answer - but I've moved to a new laptop and since @Vorspire's answer - I just tried a plain ol' commit.  It worked.

I'm running TortoiseSVN 1.7.6 on my new laptop.

Also - just checking as per @Lazy Badger's reply - I still don't have the trailing "/" - so... I guess it's the version and a "works on my machine" answer now.

Comment: Great, I only have one machine and am experiencing the exact same issue ;-( oh saad is the world lol

Comment: This is not really an answer. Please do not accept and rather let upvotes decide what should be on top of this answer list.

Answer (score 1):

When you work with SVN URL, always have trailing slash in URL. *I think*, you have wrong (this way) URL of repo in your WC

Answer (score 1):

I've recently had this problem with CodePlex, where I changed the ignored/unversiond files, and resolved it to some extent.

Instead of trying to commit the changes, which resulted in the error every time, I opened the Repo Browser (TortoiseSVN) for my local repository and deleted the newly ignored/unversioned files.

This action caused an automatic commit/update which removed the files from the remote repo and partially solved the problem.
The next step was to delete everything in my local repo, except the '.svn' directory, then use the SVN Update option to download the entire project again.

I can now continue with my commits without the error and was able to successfully delete the newly deleted/unversioned files from the remote repo.

Hope this helps.

Comment: No need to sign your answers. SO will do it automatically for you.

Answer (score 1):

It can't update the folders changes if there is a new ignored file at there. unchecking the folders (or removing the ignored file's definition) worked for me.

Comment: This answer work for me, too! Maybe it is THE answer and should be accepted?!